# Accessing many components in a page

Tags: magnolia

Using magnolia i created the area and defined many components  for a page.

```
templateScript: /lukup-bkp/templates/pages/index.jsp
renderType: jsp
visible: true
title: Lukup trial Home
dialog: lukup-bkp:pages/home
areas:
  area1:
  renderType: jsp
  availableComponents:
  quotation:
    id: lukup-bkp:components/home_com
```

And in my jsp page i am retrieving the value of the text inside the div element like this.

```
 <cms:area name="area1" />
```

If i create text field and blockquote in one area like this:

```
areas:
  area1:
  renderType: jsp
  availableComponents:
  quotation:
    id: lukup-bkp:components/home_com
  blockquote:
    id: lukup-bkp:components/block_com
```

In my jsp how i have to retrieve only the blockquote. If i retrieve like

```
<cms:area name="area1" >
```

both text values and blockquote values are assinging to the same component.

I want the value of text in one div and blockquote value in another div. How i can access this.

Comment: And how do the template scripts of your components look like? The `<cms:area>` tag iterates over the components, so it should render the components one after the another, with their respective templates.

Answer (score 1):

The `availableComponents` sub-node of an area definition in Magnolia determines the components that are available for authors/editors, i.e. content components that can be placed inside that area.

The `type` property of an area definition determines how many components can be placed inside the area by the editor. Allowed values for `type` are: `single`, `list`and `noComponent`. See the [Magnolia documentation of the area definition](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Area+definition) for further information.

The type determines how the sub-content of your area is rendered. `single` assumes that only one sub-node exists and renders it using the template script from its component definition. `list` assumes zero or more sub-nodes and renders them using the template script from their respective component definition. `noComponent` does not render the sub-components of the area.

See [Area definition - default area scripts](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Area+definition#Areadefinition-Defaultareascripts) for the area default scripts.

So it is important which type your `area1` is. I assume `list`.

If you want to assure that every component inside the area is surrounded with `<div>`s, you can write a custom area script like this (it's Freemarker, you might have to transpose that into JSP as needed):

```
[#list components as component]
    <div>
        [@cms.component content=component /]
    </div>
[/#list]
```

To render only blockquotes, you could check this in the area script as well:

```
[#list components as component]
    [#if cmsfn.metaData(content, "mgnl:template") == 'lukup-bkp:components/block_com']
        [#-- component has the blockquote template --]
        <div>
            [@cms.component content=component /]
        </div>
    [/#if]
[/#list]
```